# Wordpress Auto Updates

Tags: updates, wp-config, automatic-updates

I need to have auto updates on my Wordpress so I've followed the codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates). My need is to have all updates like from 4.2.2 to 4.2.3 and to 4.3 etc.. No FTP credentials are needed on my server.
My problem is that my WP has not been updated.
Have I done something wrong? How often does my Wordpress check for updates?

This is my `wp-config.php`, I've just added `define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);` to the original file.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'xXyYzZtT');
define('DB_USER', 'xXyYzZtT');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xXyYzZtT');
define('DB_HOST', 'xXyYzZtT');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WPLANG', 'it_IT');
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* PHP Memory */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

/* WordPress Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true);

/* Compression */
define('COMPRESS_CSS', true);
define('COMPRESS_SCRIPTS', true);
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', true);
define('ENFORCE_GZIP', true);

/* Updates */
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

*PS: `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` is not significant since my server doesn't need FTP credentials.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Wordpress admin panel to configure your auto-updates? You may have better luck there. It should be found under your "Dashboard > Updates". If you do not see it there, there is also the option of a plugin to help manage it for you:

- [Automatic Updater for Wordpress](http://pento.net/projects/automatic-updater-for-wordpress/)

Comment: I don't want to follow this way, the more plugins you use the more your site becomes vulnerable

Comment: Understandably, but I mention it just in the event you're unable to get your WP-Config to honor the update. But regarding the WP-CONFIG file the only thing you need to add to the file is: "define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);" which I see you've inserted. So I don't think you've done it wrong. 

The next question I have is when did you set this up? WP background updates are only installed at designated times. For instance, mine are setup at 7am/7pm. Have you had more than 24 hours for this to be processed?

Comment: If it has gone longer than 24 hours, then we have to confirm a few things. 1. Does your Wordpress install communicate with WordPress.org securely. 2. Your system has no version control in place preventing wordpress' wp-config autoupdate call. 3. All your wordpress files are writable for update.

Comment: Thats the point, you are right. I've installed a plugin by wordpress that checks if your installation can communicates with wordpress.org and if the file are writable, and all were fine (so I uninstalled it). I will re-check  in a complete cycle of 24 hours. How can I know when my background updates are setup?

Comment: Usually, you will be sent an email alerting you that your site has updated on an automatic update.

Comment: No email arrived, no updates done. Do I need to set up Wordpress Cron Job?

Comment: Is there a server-side setting to allow automatic background updates? I'm going crazy

Comment: Hmmm, for me to better trouble shoot, install http://wordpress.org/plugins/background-update-tester/ and post the results for me after here. You don't have to keep installed after obviously.

Comment: Here you can see my Background Update Tester: [link] (http://www.mediafire.com/view/912isaoe85jvr6c/Schermata_2015-08-27_alle_12.15.14.png)

Comment: Thanks for that Mattia, from what I can see and the base conversation it looks like you're not doing anything incorrectly. At this point my advice – as terrible as it is to give – would be to do a fresh install and setup the auto update then import all of your data and content again to ensure everything is functioning after. Sorry it's not a more immediate result.

Comment: I tried having two fresh installs (4.2.4), one on the production server (the one that hosts the Wordpress in question) and another on a simple VPS. After 24h the first WP was 4.2.4 and the second WP was already 4.3. After this experiment I'm convinced that there is something at server side that disallows auto update. The problem now is to discover what blocks what. Any idea?

Comment: I solved temporally the problem defining WP_ALTERNATE_CRON as true in the wp-config.php. The issue was related with the WP CRON that couldn't be run (the reason is still unknown, some ideas [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/scheduled-posts-still-not-working-in-282?replies=13#post-1175405) ). I found out that the CRON wasn't working while I was planning an article in the near future. Once I'll found the real reason of my problem I will place an exhaustive answer. Thanks for your time @JDCutter. If you have any idea feel free to comment.